# Any way to run the scripts in project.json just like in package.json?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, project.json

So as the title says, i am wondering if its possible to do the equivalent of "npm run " with the dotnet cli??  e.g. this snippet is from my project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc":"1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    //"MySql.Data.Core": "7.0.4-ir-191",
    //"MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.4-ir-191",
    "SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "7.1.14",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "moq":  "4.6.38-alpha",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.0"

  },
  "scripts": {
        "migrate-identity": "dotnet ef database update --context 'ApplicationDbContext'"
},
```

The migrate-identity is one i added my self, is it possible to execute this script??

Otherwise i guess i will just have a scripts folder in my project, no big deal, but still :)

Comment: The scripts in the scripts section are for certain build/publish events, i.e. `precompile`, `prepublish`, `postpublish` etc.

Comment: Yeah, i read about that. But ... i thouth it would be smart if those scripts could be executed manually aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the scripts you want in your `scripts` section in your `project.json`

```json
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "gulp mifiny-js", "gulp minify-css", "gulp remove-non-minified-files" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
}
```

I'm using `gulp` but this is the same with `npm`

[Here](http://json.schemastore.org/project) is the full project.json schema

As you can see, the scripts section can receive a bunch of different properties corresponding to different events.

```json
"scripts": {
        "type": "object",
        "description": "Scripts to execute during the various stages.",
        "properties": {
            "precompile": { "$ref": "#/definitions/script" },
            "postcompile": { "$ref": "#/definitions/script" },
            "prepack": { "$ref": "#/definitions/script" },
            "postpack": { "$ref": "#/definitions/script" },
            "prepublish": { "$ref": "#/definitions/script" },
            "postpublish": { "$ref": "#/definitions/script" },
            "prerestore": { "$ref": "#/definitions/script" },
            "postrestore": { "$ref": "#/definitions/script" },
            "prepare": { "$ref": "#/definitions/script" }
        }
    },
```

Also I see in your comment that you wish to execute them manually. It's possible with Visual Studio at least (never tried VS Code). Just use the `Task Runner Explorer`. You need to build your project in order to see your npm or gulp tasks.

I'm not able to open it using the shortcut (Ctrl + Alt + Backspace) but the window is also accessible through `View -> Other Windows -> Task Runner Explorer`

Answer (score 1):

`project.json` files are no longer supported. However, it is possible to handle it by using XML-based `csproj` files.

Example:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
...
  <Target Name="MyTarget" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="echo 'I believe you will see this message right after a successfull building'" />
  </Target>
...
</Project>
```

Result:

[image]

For further details:

[MS Docs: Mapping between project.json and csproj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#scripts)